# How Do I Reorder Bars in a Grouped Bar Chart According to Value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a grouped bar chart but I want the groups organized from lowest value for a variable to highest value.

The dataframe "habitat" consists of columns of "ï..Species", "RCP85Habitat", and "RCP26Habitat"
Here's my code:

```
habitat.m <- melt(habitat, id.vars='ï..Species')

plot.habitat<-ggplot(habitat.m, aes(ï..Species, value)) +   
geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image: A grouped barplot but values are not in order]

Any suggestions on how I get species to be displayed from lowest value of variable RCP85 to the highest value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)